# Test Controller exception: No such host is known

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm getting following errors on the test controller machine, when I'm trying to run `CodedUI Tests` remotely:

> (QTController.exe, PID 3032, Thread 12)
>   ControllerDeployment.DoDeployment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   (0x80004005): No such host is known

During controller and agent configuration no errors came up. And when I go to Manage test controller dialog in Visual Studio I can see all the agents active. But when I try to execute any CodedUI test remotely it's hanging forever.

Not sure if it's connected with the fact that I've upgraded client/controller/agents to 2012 versions recently, but I've started seeing the problem only after this upgrade.

Comment: Can you try [disabling Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-Firewall-on-or-off) temporarily to see whether that makes a difference?

Comment: i've tried already - no help

Comment: [This blog post](http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/using-notwork-isolation-in-lab-management-and-solve-some-issues/) suggests "add the Test Controller record in the private Domain LabAD (Active Directory)" on your network.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft KB 2643086](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643086/en-us):

> This issue occurs because the test agent computer sends its Network
>   Basic Input/Output System (NetBIOS) name instead of sending its Fully
>   Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) name to the test controller computer.
>   When the DNS server of the test controller computer does not have the
>   IP address mapping of the NetBIOS name of the test agent computer, the
>   issue that is described in the "Symptoms" section occurs.

You should ensure you are using fully qualified domain names (FQDN).

There is also a hotfix is available from Microsoft. However, you have to contact Microsoft Customer Support Services to obtain the hotfix.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, links break. As such, link-only answers are not recommended, and it is suggested that the important parts of the link are included in the answer.

Comment: Quick fix is to add all agents self hostnames and IPs to the controller hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, still not completely resolved but a workaround is to install Visual Studio on controller box and keeping result DB on same box.

Mostly the issue is restriction / firewall on VPN which might be blocking incoming traffic on TCP ports of machine / laptop.